# Ruby on Rails - Editor only for code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, editor, code-editor

In my previous applications I have used `WYSIWYG editor for Bootstrap` gem when it comes to text editing.

Now I am building a application where only codes will be edited (mostly `js` code).

Problem with `WYSIWYG editor for Bootstrap` gem is that it doesn't have any code markup/colors or lines for code.

Can I achieve this without any `gem/plugin` and/or what is the best option if I need to use `gem/plugin`.

*Something like image below*

[image]

Comment: we can not use let me google it for you links here, but why would not just google it? `rails gem for code makrup`

Comment: I have done it, but results I got were the same markup we have here on stackoverflow, like, ** __ `` and not a editor I was looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some editors such as [ace.c9](https://ace.c9.io/#nav=about) or [codemirror](https://codemirror.net/) that you can use, but for my use they were too heavy since I was only going to use it for preview.

What I did was to build my own by use of `HTML & CSS`.

I used `<pre>` for inserting codes and added some of my own settings such as `<var></var>`, `<param></param>`, `<val></val>` and added my own `css`:

```
pre var{color:green;}
pre param{color:blue;}
pre val{color:yellow;}


<pre>
var <var>width</var>: <val>300</val>;
<param>params</param>{
  Some code
}
</pre>
```

Using excisting editors will make it easier and has more options, but if you are looking for using a simple settings, you can do what I did.